# Can this query be faster and work with a large amount of data?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this query:

```
$sqlfb = "SELECT * FROM facebooklinks
     WHERE howmuch+10>views
       AND id NOT IN (SELECT linkid FROM views
            WHERE whoviewed='{$_SESSION['id']}'
              AND platform='$platformfb')
     ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";
```

The ideea is: i need to select 1 row from "facebooklinks" table where on that row 'howmuch'+10 it's > than views AND the ID of row from facebooklinks cannot be found in table "views" in column "linkid" AND here the "whoviewed" needs to be - with $_SESSION['id'], and 'platform'=$platformfb. And to be random.

I saw different opinions about how this will work and a lot of people told me this will not work with a large amount of data. How should i do it to work with a large amount of data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 SELECT f.* 
  FROM facebooklinks AS F
   WHERE F.VIEWS-F.howmuch<10
  AND NOT EXISTS
   (
      SELECT 1 FROM VIEWS V WHERE V.LINKID=F.ID 
         AND whoviewed='{$_SESSION['id']}' AND platform='$platformfb'
        
   )
```

Not sure if I rewrite it absolutely correct, but hope,the idea is understandable

Comment: What happened to the "pick one random"?